# Fedora 24 : acpi=off --> Can't use graphic card nvidia

Tags: acpi

I'm using actually fedora 24, but and several other distribution like ubuntu gnome 16 for example, I don't have other choose than disable acpi. If i don't do that I can't used the distribution.

The only one i can used with acpi is debian SID, but i have to change because it's was unstable with my laptop. And i can't used debian 8.5 without SID because this more unstable than SID :( !

But with fedodra, which is stable, i can't used bumblebee because acpi is off.

I have installed acpi and acpid on fedora 24.
I have the same problem with fedora 25 alpha

I worried because of acpi=off, i have a weird noze when i shutdown my laptop, and i can't used my nvidia graphic card.

What can i do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linux mint is the only distribution where i don't need to used without acpi=off for working.

A better solution for distribution like fedora,opensuse which don't work without acpi=off is to put nouveau.modeset=0 rd.driver.blacklist=nouveau instead of acpi=off for be able to use touchpad, fn shortcut etc.

If you have acpi problem and you tried several distribution and you can't without used acpi=off ,all you can do is upgrading and using unstable depot and wait and see, or beta distribution.
Each new version of Linux, I can see a better performance and better implementation of my hardware laptop.

Debian 8.6 normal and SID = Using debian normal and you can't used your wifi, it's laggy. Using debian SID and it's more lagy than normal you're CPU is like 30 %.

Fedora 24 et 25 : Fedora using last version for linux etc. SO largely better than debian. I have to used nouveau.modeset=0 rd.driver.blacklist=nouveau for working without acpi=off for be able to using touchpad fn shortcut etc.
I can't used my nvidia card 960m with nvidia driver. I tried eveything. Bumblebee-nvidia is the lost of time you're perfomrance with glxpshere are equal to you're intel graphic.

Linux Mint : Two word : THE BEST : You have to put acpi=off for the installation but after you don't need it. You have all laptop fonctionnilty working well and you can VERY easely install nvidia-driver.
The firt time i can nvidia-driver on a laptop it's amazing .

**LinuxMint for Live**